# How can i connect JSON true or false to my python script

Tags: python, json

Hello i am using python and want to connect JSON True or False to my code, so if "dummy": "True" do ... else: do ...
My JSON

```
[
  {
    "profilename": "Test3",
    "email": "email@outlook.com",
    "password": "Password2*",
    "payment": "Paypal",
    "product": "https://www.unkown.de/de/product/",
    "Dummy":"False"
  },
  {
    "profilename": "Test1",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "password": "Password1*",
    "payment": "Paypal",
    "product": "https://www.unkown.de/de/product/",
    "Dummy":"True"
  }
]
```

My python code:

```
profile_name =  "Test3"

with open('Data2.json', 'r') as handle:
    json = json.load(handle)


data = [x for x in json if x['profilename'] in profile_name]
email = (data[0]['email'])
password = (data[0]['password'])
payment = (data[0]['payment'])
product = (data[0]['product'])
dummy = (data[0]['dummy'])


def getLogin():
    if dummy = "True":      <----- This doesnt work, want to get this fixed
        import Script2
    else:
    print("starting login process")
```

So like if the "Dummy": "True" it should to the if condition and if "dummy": false it should do the else condition,
how can i do it?

Comment: Can you show the traceback please? I'm struggling to understand your question

Comment: So basically my Script takes the information from the Profile Test3, and IF the information "dummy" = "dummy": "True" then it should import Script2, and if "dummy" = "dummy": "false" it should print("starting login process")

Comment: That isn't a traceback. Also `=` is used for assignment, `==` is used for checking equality. Also, you need to deserialize the JSON and compare against a boolean `True`, not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand what your actual problem is. But here are some comments to the code you shared.

- The intendation of your last print is off.
- `import Script2` is probably not what you want. If there is a function in `Script2` import it at the top. Then just call the function.
- In the `if` you are not using `==`
- you are overwriting the `json` module with a variable called `json`

Here is a reworked version

```
import Script2
import json
with open('Data2.json', 'r') as handle:
    json_out = json.load(handle)

profile_name = ['Test1']

data = [x for x in json_out if x['profilename'] in profile_name]
email = (data[0]['email'])
password = (data[0]['password'])
payment = (data[0]['payment'])
product = (data[0]['product'])
dummy = (data[0]['Dummy']=='True')

def getLogin():
    if dummy:
        Script2.myfunction()
    else:
        print("starting login process")
```

An additional minor improvent would be to replace the list comprehension with a generator comprehension, as you don`t want a list anyways:

```
data = next(x for x in json_out if x['profilename'] in profile_name)
email = (data['email'])
password = (data['password'])
payment = (data['payment'])
product = (data['product'])
dummy = (data['Dummy']=='True')
```

Comment: So basically my Script takes the information from the Profile Test3, and IF the information "dummy" = "dummy": "True" then it should import Script2, and if "dummy" = "dummy": "false" it should print("starting login process")

Comment: I also marked the line where it should work but atm doesnt with "<------"

Comment: You've left the assignment `=` in the `if` condition with this answer, so this cannot work

Comment: @roganjosh indeed, thanks for pointing it out